# Why is my min value not working in my Material UI date textfield?

Tags: html, reactjs, input, material-ui

I am trying to add a min date from where the pick can start but the min date is not working.

```
<TextField
    id="date"
    type="date"
    defaultValue="2017-05-24"
    minDate="24/01/2019"
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true
    }}
/>
```

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/ ... it does not accept any prop named `minDate`

Comment: ShocKwav3_ it is anychance I can choose the min date?

Comment: Not with `TextField` as per the doc says. you can tryout this one maybe? : https://material-ui-pickers.dev/

Answer (score 19):

#### This should do the trick

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{inputProps: { min: "2020-05-01", max: "2020-05-04"} }}
  type="date"
  defaultValue="2019-05-24"
/>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be camel-case `inputProps`?

Comment: Kindly check out their doc for more info [material-ui textfield api](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api). Both InputProps and inputProps are different props that can be passed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to leverage the HTML [date attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#min), you can specify the `min` and `max` using `inputProps`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  input: {
    "&:valid": {
      backgroundColor: "yellow"
    },
    "&:invalid": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        InputProps={{ classes: classes }}
        type="date"
        defaultValue="2019-05-24"
        inputProps={{ min: "2019-01-24", max: "2020-05-31" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField type date]

You can find more about the constraint validation API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_constraint_validation_API).

If you are looking for a more full-featured date picker, that functionality is not provided by `TextField`. Instead, you should check out [Material UI Pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/).

Comment: I just tried your code, and it still allows me to choose before 01-24.. it is because I am using material-ui 3.9.3 version?

Comment: I've added some (ugly) styling to show whether or not the date is valid (i.e. meets the constraints). The exact behavior is dependent on the browser as far as what it lets the user enter.

Comment: `max` works, but `min` doesn't work for me! why?

Comment: @HamidrezaSoltani `min` works in the sandbox from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this as inputProps.

```
                    inputProps={{
                      max: "2020-01-01",
                      min: "1993-01-01"
                    }}
```